# catch is running even with code going right

Tags: php, try-catch

I'm using try catch on my application, but everything on try works, but still returning the catch.
the register is saved on DB, but still on catch

```
        try
        {

                    $sql = new Sql();
                    $results = $sql->select("CALL sp_save_lead(:name, :email, :phone, :idOrigin, :comments)", array(
                            ":name"=>$this->getname(),
                            ":email"=>$this->getemail(),
                            ":phone"=>$this->getphone(),
                            ":idOrigin"=>$this->getid_Origin(),
                            ":comments"=>$this->getcomments()
                    )); 

                        //$this->setData($results[0]);

                        $id = $results[0]["idLead"];

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        header("Location: /admin/leads/?msg=Error");
                        exit;
        } finally {
                        header("Location: /admin/leads/".$id."/?msg=Success");
                        exit;
        }
```

Must execute finally

Comment: So what does `$e` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I was expecting and normal PHP Exception, I should expect a PDOException. So I just changed the following:

"} catch (\Exception $e) {" to "} catch (\PDOException $e) {"

```
    try
    {

                $sql = new Sql();
                $results = $sql->select("CALL sp_save_lead(:name, :email, :phone, :idOrigin, :comments)", array(
                        ":name"=>$this->getname(),
                        ":email"=>$this->getemail(),
                        ":phone"=>$this->getphone(),
                        ":idOrigin"=>$this->getid_Origin(),
                        ":comments"=>$this->getcomments()
                )); 

                    //$this->setData($results[0]);

                    $id = $results[0]["idLead"];

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
                    header("Location: /admin/leads/?msg=Error");
                    exit;
    } finally {
                    header("Location: /admin/leads/".$id."/?msg=Success");
                    exit;
    }
```